# Putty - how to tell which encryption algorithm is actually being used

Tags: encryption, putty

I know how to configure which algorithms I'm willing to use. But the actual algorithm used is based on negotiation between putty and the server. So how do I tell which algorithm is actually being used, once a connection is established?

Answer (score 1):

After making your connection in PuTTY, you can open the "Event Log" to see the negotiated encryption and MAC algorithms.

[image: PuTTY Event Log]

You can access the event log opening the session menu by clicking on the PuTTY icon in the top-left corner of the window.

Comment: And as an interesting aside, you can force a re-negotiation by opening the menu and selecting "Special Command" -> "Repeat key exchange"